# Trying to make a Navbar that has tabs, one tab has dropdown, on mobile devices the tabs become hamburger menu, which is animated

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to make my Navbar have a few specific things.

I want it to:
-Be fixed at the top
-Have tabs, including one tab with a dropdown menu.
-Turn into a hamburger menu responsively on mobile
-Have the hamburger menu be animated smoothly.

I've been changing attributes between the code I have from MDBootstrap. 
It gives me:
-the fixed navigation top bar
-the colours I want
-The hamburger menu, and a dropdown tab
-Animated hamburger menu

The problem is that even on the wide browser windows, the hamburger menu is there.

I want the hamburger menu to only show if the browser isn't wide enough.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler third-button" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent22"
aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent22" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
```

I'm just not sure how to combine the responsive topnav I've found here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/navs/

Into the great MDBoostrap version.  Can anyone help?

Comment: This might help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries (you use different css rules based on the media type/size used to display the page)

Comment: Alright I'll try that! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [pen](https://codepen.io/mistermoody/pen/yEZKwg) I made; I believe I used the same resource from W3 that you referenced~

HTML

```
<body>
    <header class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#" class="active">Responsive Navigation</a>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#">Link 6</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </header>
    <main>
        <p>A Responsive Navigation system that is Fixed on Desktop.</p> 
        <p>On mobile devices, a Hamburger Icon will be displayed in the upper-right corner. Click it once to open the navigation, then click it again to close.</p>
    </main>
</body>
```

JS

```
function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
            x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
            x.className = "topnav";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Awesome. I’m still new to his app. But I’ll check it out as soon as I figure out how to haha

Comment: Codepen is a great designer asset. Once you create the nav component, you can store the code there. It's also a good destination for creative inspiration~

Comment: I’ll definitely check it out!